# Docker Running SQL Server: Connection Refused Error

Tags: java, sql-server, docker, aws-lambda

I am running Microsoft SQL Server on via Docker on my local system. I can connect to my database locally using Azure Data Studio. However, when attempting to connect via my IDE using JAVA and I get the following error:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host localhost, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Connection refused. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall

The code that I am running is the following:

```
try {
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    new ScriptRunner(DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=mars_db;user=sa;password=sysAdmin123;encrypt=false"))
                    .runScript(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(script)));
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
}
```

As stated above, I can connect to my local instance via Azure Data Studio. What am I doing wrong with the Java code.

Here is the build.gradle as well

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-core:1.2.2'
    implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-lambda-java-events:3.11.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc:12.4.1.jre11'

    implementation 'org.mybatis:mybatis:3.5.13'
}

sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11
```

Comment: Is the Java code actually running on the Docker host itself, or is it running inside a Docker container? When running inside a Docker container... unless you also have an SQL Server instance installed in the same container then `localhost:1433` isn't going to connect to anything. In these cases you  might have more success with `host.docker.internal`.

Comment: This is an aws-lambda function. That being said, when I start it up in IntelliJ, the lambda function is started in its own container.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by using `ifconfig` in the terminal to find the ip address of my running docker instance. Due to the fact that when I start my AWS Lambda function from my IDE, the Lambda is started in a totally different container than the one that my database is running in. Therefore, I have to reference the ip address of the docker instance that is running the database.